# Testing ES2015 class with Intern v4

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

How do I import my class and write unit tests using Intern v4. I keep running into an error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

Unit test file demo.js:

```
import Demo from '../../app/demo.js';

const { suite, test } = intern.getInterface('tdd');
const { assert } = intern.getPlugin('chai');
const { expect } = intern.getPlugin('chai');
```

Demo.js class:

```
class Demo{
  constructor(){

  }

  print(){
    console.log(`hello world`);
  }

}

export default {Demo};
```

Answer (score 3):

JS's module system (import/export) isn't natively supported by many environments yet. To use that syntax you'll need to use a module loader like SystemJS, or babel-register (see [this page](https://theintern.io/docs.html#Intern/4/docs/docs%2Fhow_to.md/test-es-modules) in the docs).

Most of the examples for Intern 4 assume tests are written in TypeScript and then built to CommonJS or AMD/UMD modules.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use Gulp with Babel and test the bundled file? Sorry new to unit testing and cannot find any examples of testing ES6 modules or plain javascript

Comment: If you're using a bundler like webpack, the generated bundle will be in a browser-compatible syntax, and you can include it in intern's `suites` list.

Comment: For babel, you could use babel-register to test your code as-is, or use babel to [translate your code to CommonJS modules](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/).

Comment: Thanks, Do you have a quick demo or a code reference that I could take a look at?

Comment: I created a demo based ( [Github](https://github.com/neil-coutinho/es-gulp-babel-intern)) on your suggestion of using Babel to transpile to CommonJS. Was wondering if you could maybe take a look and let me know how I can improve things.

Answer (score 1):

Like @jason0x43 says you must use a loader to load your ESModule to test.
For exemple with babel-register, in your intern.json file you need :

```
"plugins": [
    "node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js"
]
```

But this doesn't load your test files. So if your test files are also ESModules you can use [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) in combination with [babel-register](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/#top).

`babel-register` is already loaded by `intern` so just add a `.babelrc` file with :

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```